British general orders artillery attack French allies
It's an older black-and-white film about a world war (WW1, I think). 
In it, there's a scene in the middle of the film where a large group of British and French soldiers "charge the anthill" (i.e. run up with rifles to try and capture a German fortification), and get gunned down by the hundreds by machine gun nests. 
At one point, a British general notices that a company of French troops are just hiding in the trenches rather than charging, and orders an artillery attack on the French. The officer in charge of artillery declines the request, citing a requirement for written confirmation, despite repeated threats from the general.
Later, after a lengthy legal battle, about 5 of the French soldiers are sentenced to death by firing squad for insubordination (the French general contended that nobody should be executed, as the English plan to charge the anthill was asinine while the British general contended that all French soldiers from that particular company should be executed). 
One of the French soldiers slated to be executed accidentally injures his head while in prison, and is actually propped up to a post for his execution. At the end of the film, two high ranking officials from the British and French military meet to discuss the execution, and the British official is horrified when he discovers the attempt by the British general to order artillery attacks on allied troops. 
At the end, the general, realizing his career is finished, states "you have betrayed the only innocent man in this affair" (or something similar).

Paths of Glory (1957)

After refusing to attack an enemy position, a general accuses the soldiers of cowardice and their commanding officer must defend them.






Paths of Glory is a 1957 American anti-war film by Stanley Kubrick based on the novel of the same name by Humphrey Cobb. Set during World War I, the film stars Kirk Douglas as Colonel Dax, the commanding officer of French soldiers who refuse to continue a suicidal attack. Dax attempts to defend them against a charge of cowardice in a court-martial.
...
The next morning, the attack on the Anthill proceeds. Dax leads the first wave of soldiers over the top into no man's land under heavy fire. None of the men reach the German trenches, and B Company refuse to leave their own trench after sustaining heavy casualties. Mireau, enraged, orders his artillery to open fire on them to force them onto the battlefield. The artillery commander refuses to fire on his own men without written confirmation of the order. Meanwhile, Dax returns to the trenches, and tries to rally B Company to join the battle, but as he climbs out of the trench, the body of a dead French soldier knocks him down. Predictably, the attack was a failure.
...
Dax, who was a criminal defense lawyer in civilian life, volunteers to defend the men at their court-martial. The trial however, is a farce, and can accurately be described as a kangaroo court where the rights of the accused are violated. There is no formal written indictment, a court stenographer is not present, and the court refuses to admit evidence that would support acquittal. In his closing statement, Dax challenges the court's authenticity, and requests mercy, saying, "Gentlemen of the court, to find these men guilty would be a crime to haunt each of you till the day you die." Nonetheless, the three men are sentenced to death.
Wikipedia

